Why does Leo see Sidney’s beneficial offer as blackmail?
At Toots Shor’s Restaurant, Sidney, a press agent, casually asks Leo, a
columnist, about his upcoming article on cigarette girls. He reveals his
source as Rita, a cigarette girl, and expresses his regret at not having
met Leo’s wife:

Sidney: You know what I wonder, Leo? I wonder maybe you can use a
hot little item for tomorrow's column.
Leo Bartha: What is this, blackmail? Beat it.

Why does Leo see Sidney’s beneficial offer as blackmail?

According to the plot summary in Wikipedia, Leo was having an affair with Rita.
